# What addon should I use to sync/backup my installed addons?

Tags: google-chrome, backup, sync, browser-addons

Is there a addon collection manager in Chrome? In Firefox, we have FEBE. In Chrome, I don't know what is the similar one.

Comment: Chrome 5 sync preferences, bookmarks and themes, but still NO addons... Can't wait for them to put all that stuff in the cloud as well

Comment: a duplicated, updated and answered question: http://superuser.com/questions/194502/google-chrome-extension-to-synchronize-extensions

Answer (score 0):

From [Google Chrome help forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=02172ce4d45743a1&hl=en):

> I use these two tools to backup my
>   chrome extensions, bookmarks, etc.
>
> 1)  Favbackup
>
> 2)  Google Chrome Backup
>
> Both of these are profiled here:
>
> _http://www.favbrowser.com/backup/
>
> _http://www.parhelia-tools.com/products/gcb/googlechrome.aspx

Didn't try these tools myself so I can't garantee they work.

P.S. Sorry, had to obfuscate direct links to tools sites: spam prevention mechanism did not allow me to post more than one hyperlink as new user :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed "sync" feature request, so this is only partial solution.