# Google chrome extension to synchronize extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I want to have same extensions on my pen drive chrome, windows at work, and mac at home... And no, [Chrome does not sync them (just the data)](https://superuser.com/questions/154770/how-to-export-extensions-of-google-chrome/154772#154772)! Anything that facilitates this process is welcome. I'm just asking for an extension because it's probably the easiest path. I'd welcome even something that just drops me a list of my installed extensions and make it clickable so I can go and install one by one.

Actually [it seems like there's already a way to do exactly that](https://superuser.com/questions/154770/how-to-export-extensions-of-google-chrome/167835#167835). But I haven't tested it and it looks too complicated for regular users. So, again, extension anyone? :P

edit: Just as another reference, and it may help other people who might want just that, I've found [a way to do backup and restore on windows](http://www.parhelia-tools.com/products/gcb/googlechrome.aspx). Again, not what I'm looking for. I don't want windows only, and I don't need a tool to manage profiles or do backup. It's more of a sync than backup. So I even changed the title.

Comment: Yo dawg, I herd u liek extensions so we put in an extension that allows you to sync extensions so you can extension while you extension!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need an extension. Just go to Chrome preferences and click "Personal Stuff" and choose "Set Up Sync..." Then enter your Google account information. Repeat this for all the computers you want synchronized. This will sync everything, passwords, *extensions*, bookmarks, etc. When setting up the sync, you can also specify what to sync if you only want extensions.

Comment: Got it configured. Extensions are NOT synced. Just their data, if you've got same ones installed.

Comment: @Cawas: It only works for extensions that you installed from Chrome's Extension gallery. If you downloaded a random .crx from somewhere, it will not be synced.

Comment: @Matthew I've only installed extensions from chrome's gallery. till few days ago I didn't even know it was possible to do it from outside. and still no extension is synced.

Comment: @Cawas: That sounds like a serious problem. You should file a bug against Chromium with more details (http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) (Chrome bugs are filed against Chromium).

Comment: @Matthew that'd be big news to me. Will do as soon as I can verify and reproduce everything! :o

Comment: Well, whatever was the bug, it's been fixed... Chrome just rock!