# FEBE-like extension for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google chrome extension to synchronize extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/194502/google-chrome-extension-to-synchronize-extensions)

FEBE = Firefox Extensions Backup Extension. Use it to back up your extensions and install them on a new machine in one simple action.

Is there anything similar for Google Chrome? (On Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently do not know such extension. However, an application that does what you need is available: http://www.parhelia-tools.com/products/gcb/googlechrome.aspx

Answer (score 5):

**Extension backup is built right in!**

I found that all I needed to do what go to Chrome's Options and then click the Sync button.

[image: sync settings]

Comment: Note: I've seen it mentioned that this won't actually back up or sync the extensions! Only the extensions' locally stored data will be synced, apparently?